# Cannot connect slave1:8088 in hadoop 2.7.2

Tags: hadoop

I am new in hadoop and I have installed hadoop 2.7.2 into two machines which are master and slave1. I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.edureka.co/blog/setting-up-a-multi-node-cluster-in-hadoop-2.X). It was not mentioned in the tutorial but I have also edited JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_CONF_DIR variables in hadoop-env.sh. At the end I have two machines hadoop installed. In master NameNode, DataNode, SecondaryNameNode, ResourceManager and NodeManager are running and in slave1 DataNode and NodeManager are running.

I am able to go to master:8088 in the browser and when I go http://master:8088/cluster/nodes, there is only master node here. I am not able to go isci17:8088 and that is not a live node. Why could it be?

Comment: can you share the screen shot of the error

Comment: there is no error screen. I think, I should be able to see 2 live nodes, instead I have only 1 live node which is the master node.

Comment: I am confused here. Which url is Isci17:8088 ? And can you elaborate the previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 8088 is the resource manager web ui port, so if it is running on master you probably won't have it on the slave.

You should be able to also go to the name node web ui on port 50070 on your name node as well to see status such as http://master:50070/ and the MapReduce JobHistory Server at http://hostname:19888/ for a web ui.

If you have access to a terminal session you run the following command on each server as root/sudo user to see which ports are listening on which server in a Linux terminal session;

sudo lsof -i tcp | grep -i LISTEN

You also also run hadoop cli commands that will give you info;
You can run the following to check hadoops ports in a terminal session.

hdfs portmap

Other Health checks on command line;
hdfs classpath
hdfs getconf -namenodes
hdfs dfsadmin -report -live
hdfs dfsadmin -report -dead
hdfs dfsadmin -printTopology

Depending on if the hadoop cli command works automatically you might have to find the executable to run ./hdfs. Also depending on distro/version you might have to replace the command hdfs with the command hadoop.

If you want to see your cluster configurations check your /etc/hadoop/conf folder along with /etc/hadoop/hive . You will find about 5-10 *-site.xml files. There configuration files contain your clusters configuration with the hostnames and ports.